# <a> in <div> in <li> - when I click the list item, the link opens

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have built an expandable tree, using nested UL's. Here is the simplified code of what I have:

```
<li>
    <div><a href="somepage">Link</a></div>
    <ul>...</ul>
</li>
```

The `<li>` has a `padding-left` of 20px and a background image of either a plus or a minus. I have a click event on the `<li>`, to toggle a class and save the current state in a cookie. When I click it, it seems as if the `<a>` is clicked - it gets a dashed outline and the page location changes. However, the `<li>` click event is also executed - the tree expands. I would like to only have the `<li>` click event executed.

It works fine in IE8+, Chrome and Firefox, just not in IE7. In case it is of any interest: I use jQuery to bind the click event to the `<li>`.

---

**EDIT**: As suggested in a comment by T.J. Crowder, I added a jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hVZv/). EDIT 2: changed the jQuery selector. Still same behaviour, though.

---

**UPDATE**: It is actually IE9 in IE7 mode, would that make a difference?

Comment: For people to help, you're going to have to put together a small, self-contained example and post the code in the question (and possibly also to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net, so people can play with it live, but do put it *in the question* as well).

Comment: Can you show your jQuery code?

Comment: according to your fiddle it does not actually trigger the <a> to be clicked.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hVZv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution is quite easy: use actual IE7, instead of IE9's IE7 mode.

Sorry to bother you, folks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong: Div is not allowed within ul.

However, you can try to prevent the click event of the link.

```
$(function() {
    $('#tree div').click(function() {this.style.background = '#00FF00'; });
    $('#tree a').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault(); });
});
```

Comment: I have no `<div>` directly within `<ul>`, and `<div>` within `<li>` is perfectly allowed. And I'm not looking to stop the click event entirely, I just want it to not click when I don't click the anchor but just the li around it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mixed up li and ul in your example. Additionally, I got your question wrong. Sorry for that.